# JPA - Using @Id on a non-unique column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, sql-view

I have a read-only database view, `Employee`, with several columns including two called `code` and `description`. `code` is not unique. For example,

```
name code description
bob  ft   full time
sue  ft   full time
tom  pt   part time
cat  tm   temporary
mat  ft   full time
```

Because of the way the view is built though, I know that the same `code` will always have the same `description`.

I'm only interested in getting a distinct list of `code`s and `description`s.

This approach seems to work:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table("Employee")
public class Code {

  @Id
  private String code;

  private String description;

}

@Repository
public interface CodeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Code, String> {
} 

@Service
public class CodeService {

  private CodeRepository codeRepo;

  public List<Code> getCodes() {
      return CodeRepository.findAll();
   }
}
```

Is there a problem with this approach since `code` is not really an primary key?

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is to call this `findAll` method, this is "ok", but doesn't the list contain duplicates? IMO it would be clearer if you were using `distinct` here.